# Создание сайта путем "рисования" его в Adobe Illustrator(AI)

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, adobe

Как это происходит? Сайты состоят из html кода, css и js(я про визуальную часть).

Или я напутал чего и в AI рисуется только макет, а потом уже (как все выше)?

P.S. Достаточно будет пнуть в правильном направлении. Я просто запутался. Спасибо.

Comment: Часто люди которые рисуют макет и верстают сайт - это разные люди, с разным разным набором умений, знаний и инструментов.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman всмысле везде пишут, как мы создавали сайт в AI, но как происходит создание его как сайта? AI используют для верстки или я чего напутал и AI используют как инструмент для макета?

Comment: Из моего опыта: дизайнер создавал макеты в Photoshop и потом их обсуждал с верстальщиком и front-end разработчиком. Последние же брали из макета картинки и пр. графические элементы, а затем уже делали сайт. Они пользовались простыми редакторами для кода.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman спасибо большое, вы ответили на мой вопрос. Мне показалось, что сайты либо пишут(как я писал) или создают просто в AI, который потом является сайтом.

Comment: Я не дизайнер и не верстальщик. Так что последних веяний я не знаю.